# PHP7.0 & Informix DB connection

Tags: informix, php-7.0

I am trying to connect to an Informix db remotely via php7.0
Im on Ubuntu 16.04
Have downloaded the Informix CSDK and have done the default installation and this is the path to informix:

/opt/IBM/Informix

Also downloaded PDO_INFORMIX-1.3.1 and as per IBM manual, next step is compiling where I am running into issue:
Commands that I run are:

1. phpize

2  ./configure --with-pdo-informix=/opt/IBM/informix`

getting error `configure: error: Cannot find php_pdo_driver.h`

EDIT:

I was successful in configuring the driver. Using this link:
https://github.com/BitDesert/pdo_informix-php7

Now when I connect to the remote Informix DB, I get this PHP error:

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE=HY000, SQLDriverConnect: -11005 [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver]Unspecified System Error = -11005. in /var/www/html/informix.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/informix.php(7): PDO->__construct('informix:host=3...', 'ReadOnly', 'nowriting') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/informix.php on line 7

not able to find a solution for this yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the online [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.em.doc/errors.html) error `-11005` is `Invalid connection string attribute`. Check your connection string.

Comment: Yo Luis, thanks for your comment mate. I was able to sort out the issue. Turned out that the connection string should not have any spaces or line breaks. After that I ran into other issues like configuring environment variables for Informix but sorted that out as well. I am now able to connect to the Informix DB using PHP7